# LiteTouch deployment fails when BIOS is set to IDE but works when set to AHCI

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, deployment, imaging

I have an HP Z420 Workstation with a single 500GB SATA drive that I spent all day imaging to Server 2012 R2. Part of the deployment process is selecting if you want to wipe the drive. I selected yes every time because the drive was blank. It failed numerous times with the error `LiteTouch Deployment failed, Reason Code -214746259 0x80004005`. I exited to a command prompt and ran these commands:

```
diskpart
select disk 0
clean
```

Then I restarted the deployment. Still failed. I checked and rechecked BIOS settings, and I saw nothing out of the ordinary, but I did see that the drive mode was set to IDE. I decided to enable AHCI to t ake advantage of the better features. The LiteTouch deployment went smoothly after that.

So my question is this: Do I potentially have an error in my deployment script that is causing the failed deployments to IDE or is this a hardware issue that I should investigate further?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The driver required by the Disk controller is not the same if it is set up as IDE or AHCI.

So I guess your deployment does have the driver for AHCI and not the driver for IDE..

Comment: This likely results from the IDE driver missing from the reference image.

Comment: Sometimes you read an answer and it makes such perfect sense that you kick yourself for not realizing the simplicity of the solution. I totally could have seen that forest if not for all these trees! xD